# FAU Dissertation tex template error

Tags: templates

I am getting an error when I try to compile a sample Dissertation tex template:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (MiKTeX 2.9)
entering extended mode
("C:\Users\bossman\Desktop\FAU Disseration\fausample.tex"
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9k> and hyphenation patterns for 68 languages loaded.
("C:\Users\bossman\Desktop\FAU Disseration\fauthesis.cls"
Document Class: fauthesis 2014/09/23 v1.0 (C. Beetle)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\report.cls"
Document Class: report 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size12.clo"))
! Undefined control sequence.
l.232 ^^I^^I\ifnum\pdfoutput
                             > 0^^I^^I^^I^^I^^I^^I^^I^^I^^I% Test if \pdfout...
```

Here is the .cls code from line 232:

```
% This checks carefully if the \pdfoutput command is defined, and then sets the PDF page margins. 
% 
{\expandafter}\expandafter\ifx\csname pdfoutput\endcsname\relax\else    
% Test if \pdfoutput not defined
    \ifx\pdfoutput\relax\else   % Test if \pdfoutput not previously tested      
        \ifnum\pdfoutput > 0    Test if \pdfoutput active
           \@foundpdflatextrue          
           \setlength\pdfpageheight{11in}%
            \setlength\pdfpagewidth{8.5in}%         
        \fi\fi\fi
```

I have updated the console window text above.  Can you tell me what other information will be helpful?

I an using WinEdt to complie the tex file.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I doubt that is possible to track the error from that fragment only. You should give us more information!

Comment: I have updated the text from the Console window.  Can you tell me what other information will be helpful?

Comment: Joe: That information does not really help. We need at least a `.tex` file which does reproduce the error. Where can we find your strange template file?

Comment: It doesn't look as if this class is meant to work with xelatex. Why don't you use pdflatex?

Comment: Hello, I also tried pdflatex but that also gave me an error.  Here is a hyperlink to the FAU website with the files and tex file "fausample.tex" and the required fauthesis.cls:     http://physics2.fau.edu/~cbeetle/FAUThesis/#files

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I just tested, the template runs fine with pdflatex. Do you want to write up a short answer? Or better close the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ulrike Fischer offered the solution to use pdflatex.